# adb pushed file into the download folder not visible in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am pushing some files in the download folder of the emulator. I do that by typing:

```
adb push test.jpg /sdcard/Download
```

The file is listed properly. I downloaded a picture with Android Chrome to make sure I am storing the file in the proper location and has the same permissions and owner.

I cannot make the file to appear in the Download App. What am I missing? I sent a broadcast as well and no luck:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard
```

The file is not visible at all in Android.